# Examples of <link> tag in a HTML using different 'rel' attributes?

Tags: html, xhtml

Could someone provide meaningful examples of HTML `<link>` tag with different values of "rel" attribute?

Apart from the possible values explanation for the "rel" attribute, are there any practical uses for the different values (other than stylesheet value)?

Comment: Do you mean the `<a>` tag?

Comment: i never use rel attribute. but i am sure there is a use for it

Comment: updated my question, highlighting `<link>` tag.

Comment: I need your help.
Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546478/14467588.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a number of useful examples, I would recommend looking here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html.

This looks like a very concise, slightly easier to navigate version of w3: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#rel-alternate

Comment: Yes, I got the explanations. Wanted to see practical examples. Thx.

Comment: @zippymind Sorry for not getting the examples sooner, but if you haven't, please double-check the second link I posted.

Comment: There are practical examples on that site. In fact, all the _standard_ values are listed: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes

Comment: @DiegoAgulló Like he said, he wants examples, not just explanations. The link you've posted is great, but has no tangible examples.

Comment: Thanks @NathanWhite, the second link provides clear usage examples and supported browsers as well.

Answer (score 1):

There aren’t that many meaningful real-life examples of `link` elements, apart from `rel=stylesheet`. There are various lists of `rel` values that might be used, with definitions and ideas of how they *might* be used by browsers or search engines, but little actual evidence of such use. But some elements that have real effects in some cases are:

`<link rel=icon ...>` defines a shortcut icon for the page; widely recognized by browsers and user by authors

`<link rel=alternate ...>` is described in [Google instructions](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=189077), so Google presumably does something with it

`<link rel=canonical ...>` suggested in [other Google instructions](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=189077)

`<link rel=prefetch ...>` causes the referenced page to be preloaded, in some browsers

Comment: Addendum: [rel/prev](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html), [author](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986) is only used by Google/G+ right now.

Answer (score 0):

At https://www.sitepoint.com/rel-html-attribute/ they state

> The "alternate" attribute value may also be used in the context of XML
>   feeds, namely RSS or Atom, which are indicated with the type
>   attribute

Also, site navigation with rel="first|last|prev|next" is supposed to make navigation easier and is e.g. used by a specific firefox extension (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/site-navigation-bar/?src=search).

Answer (score 0):

I Only know 'icon' value, you can set pavicon of your HTML page that appear on browser tab, using:

```
<link rel="icon" type="icon" href="path/to/youricon.ico" />
```

hopely useful: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

Answer (score 0):

examples:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<link rel="icon" href="image.png">

<link itemprop="URL" href="http://...">

<link rel="next" href="page3.php">

<link rel="author license" href="author_license.php">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
```

more examples: [link element](https://web.archive.org/web/20140125084249/http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_link_tag.php) and [rel attribute on link element](https://web.archive.org/web/20140311153752/http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/link/html5_link_rel_attribute.php)